# The spectral norm of $A$ is bigger than that of $B$, then $A-B$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given are $A$ and $B$ symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

If $A - B$ is positive semi-definite, then the spectral norm of $A$ is bigger than that of $B$.

The question is that:

Given then the spectral norm of $A$ is bigger than that of $B$, can we derive  $A - B$ is positive semi-definite?

Many thanks.

Comment: In the first statement, you need $A$ and $B$ are also positive semi-definite, or you can set $A=-I,B=-2I$, then $A-B=I$ is positive semi-definite, but $\|A\| =1<\|B\| = 2$.

Comment: In the first statement, I do not need A and B to be positive semi-definite.

Comment: if A=-I, then A is negative semi-definite.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Let $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$, $B = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{array}\right]$. Then $\|A\|_2 = 3$, $\|B\|_2 = 2$. Thus $\|A\|_2 > \|B\|_2$. But $C = A - B = \left[\begin{array}{cc}2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right]$ is not semi-positive definite.

Comment: Many thanks. I have another question.  Given A is n by d matrix. A=U W V^T. U and V are n by r and d by r matrix with  orthogonal columns. W is a r by r positive diagonal matrix containing the singular values of A. V_k be V with all but their first k columns zeroed out. If trace(E)<= trace(AV_k V_k^TA^T), can we get AA^T- E is positive semi-definite?

Comment: No, but this is a different question. I can't give you a counter example here.